# Get next column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a table of permissible stress (pink) values for slenderness ratio (green) and yield strength (blue) from local govt byelaws.

Taking values using `df.at[A, B]`, where A and B are variables coming from pre-processes, say A = 100 and B = 250, I want to take values 110 from (green) and 72 (from pink).

What I have tried:

1. I need these values for interpolation, I have tried *interpolation methods* which come with pandas, but for the particular use case, I need to interpolate these values mathematically.
2. I have also tried taking values from index, by first finding index of the value, and then adding 1 to the index, but that method is not a viable option for various reasons.
3. I have also tried simply adding the column value interval to the A and B values, but as can be observed, while the green values (A) is uniform and incremental, the value intervals for yield strength (B) (in blue), while incremental, is not uniform.

[edit 2]

4. I am have tried df.where, There should be another way to find co-ordinates of a value.

I have been stuck for a while, any help/suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks!

[image: steel table]

Comment: can you provide us a minimum working example of your python script too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood what you are trying to achieve. If I got it right, you want to get the pink value based on the slenderness ratio index that follows a certain value und a yield strength at a specific value (or column).

```
df.loc[np.roll(df.index == A, shift=1), B]
```

This would shift the logical index (green) by one.

Comment: Thank you! This approach has helped me a lot! Just a little thing, when I print the result, it prints ***Name: 250, dtype: int64*** after the values, can I suppress that?

Comment: can I split the result values 110 and 72 into two separate variabes?

Comment: Yes, you could just do `df.loc[np.roll(df.index == A, shift=1), B].iloc[0]` or `df.loc[np.roll(df.index == A, shift=1), B].values` (numpy array) depending on what you need. And regarding splitting the values, just do:

`row = np.roll(df.index == A, shift=1)` and use that for getting the pink value
`slenderness = df.index[row]` and then as before `stress = df.loc[row, B]`.